# Recurring issue where I can only connect to major sites like Google and Apple

Tags: dns, home-networking

I have a recurring connectivity issue whereby I am only able to connect to major sites like Google and Apple. 99% of the web gives me a timeout when trying to connect. This happens simultaneously on 2 different PCs - a Windows based laptop and as well as a Linux (Ubuntu) workstation on the same home network.

I don't have a problem streaming Netflix via my Apple TV also on the same network.

Rebooting my router only occasionally seems to fix the issue. Normally I need to wait overnight, rebooting both my PC and router before the issue goes away.

So what exactly is happening? I assume it has something to do with DNS lookup.

How can I prevent this from happening again? Or is this a problem with my service provider?

Comment: It would probably be beneficial to know your DNS settings... Output of `ipconfig /all` for the relevant Windows adapter and `nmcli show device` for relevant Linux adapter... If you could add those to your original question it would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this could be an ISP problem.  This sounds like the nameservers you have on file for your network may be invalid.

The reason you can probably connect with Google or Apple might be that they have hard-coded IP addresses.

If you cannot resolve other hostnames, look to see what DNS servers you're using on your network.

You can use Google's public DNS servers at: 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 in place of any ones your ISP may have that are not functioning properly.

Also try re-booting your router(s).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is most likely with the DNS server you/your ISP is using. It could be that they have some internal server issues, overload or other kinds of issues resolving the IP address for the hostname you try to request. The easiest way to fix this is by using a different DNS server. Google's is probably one of the most reliable ones. ([See this list for a couple public and free DNS servers](https://www.lifewire.com/free-and-public-dns-servers-2626062))

Given you have no access to your router's menu, you can put the following inside of your `/etc/resolv.conf` file on the linux machine:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

This will use Google's public DNS servers.

If you have access to your router's menu, set the primary DNS server to `8.8.8.8` and the secondary DNS server to `8.8.4.4`. Those settings are usually under the connection/DHCP/cable/etc. settings. Under `dd-wrt` you can find them on the `setup` page (`static DNS 1` and `static DNS 2`).

The reason Apple works might be that iTunes adds some custom entires to your `hosts` file on Windows, so the IPs won't be resolved through your regular DNS servers. I suspect something similar is going on with Google too.